# Disable Column 'column_name' cannot be null with mysql

Tags: mysql

So I receive "Column 'column_name' cannot be null" whenever I try to insert NULL into a column that is specified with NO NULL.
I can do INSERT IGNORE which would work fine but I prefer not to do it that way.

I am pretty sure there is a global variable that I can set so to disable this validation in db.
I thought I enabled strict-mode in @@global.sql_mode but it was empty.

Please let me know if you know which variable I should change to disable this error!
Many thanks guys!

Comment: Check if that column has the flag with not null enabled.

Comment: Change the column to *not* NOT NULL. Problem solved.

Comment: Also, the constraint is there for a reason - why would you try to disable it? And what if the application using the database expects it to be a NOT NULL field and gets a NULL? Are you sure it will be ok?

Comment: What would you like to happen when one attempts to insert such a record?  Should the `INSERT` succeed?  If so, what should be the value in `column_name`?  Should it fail silently?  If so so, why do you wish not to use `IGNORE`?

Comment: Hey guys, Thank you for your replies!
Some other things that I should have mentioned:
1. I can't disable NOT NULL because those columns are one of the primary keys.
2. I have set default values to those columns, but for some reason it doesn't pick up the default value even if the input is null.

I want default value to be used whenever null is entered. As I mentioned, INSERT IGNORE is perfect, except that this problem is actually ubiquitous to most of the tables in the db, so I prefer to switch a global variable, which seems to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: I just realize that default value is only used when that column is not specified (not even NULL) - is there anything to project NULL to default value for columns having NOT NULL? (I know about COALESCE but once again, I am looking more of a global variable switch rather than having to this to all the queries)

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER column_name SET DEFAULT default_value;
```

I suppose that the not null flag was with a point. Add the default_value to your liking ( I guess 0 ). Also this works if the column is NOT text/blob.